# how many ways we can get a 3 cards from a deck (52 card 4 types) that every sequence is sorted ??

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

i mean get a seqeuences(length 3) that every right number equal/bigger than left one
example (1 2 3)  (J,Q,K)  (7,7,7)

no return cards

i think to do 52C3/3!
but in the solve its not right way ?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  How are you ordering the cards?  Just by rank?  So then $\{2\spadesuit, 2\heartsuit, 2\clubsuit\}$ would yield $6$ solutions?

Comment: For what its worth, in some games suits are taken into account and it truly is a total order on the cards.  Bridge does this for instance, ranking $\clubsuit < \diamondsuit < \heartsuit < \spadesuit$.  In any event, for each of the $\binom{52}{3}$ subsets of cards possible, there is either one order for them or (*if you allow it*) more than one order for them that is valid.  We would want to *increase* our count here if at all to compensate, not decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If the cards had a total order the answer would be $52 \choose 3$ because you can choose three cards in that many ways.  One of those selections would have them in order.  This is not quite right because cards of equal rank are not ordered, so there are six ways to draw $7S, 7H, 7D$ and have them acceptable instead of $1$.  You need to account for this.  There are also additional orders for cases of a pair plus another card.